# Lock Chrome (mobile -Android) to Portrait

Tags: css, html, mobile, screen-orientation, portrait

I tried this in my stylesheets.

```
   @viewport {
    orientation: portrait; 
  }
```

The screen still rotates.

I've seen many solutions involving JQuery. I am looking for a Jquery-less solution due to file weight restrictions. And I am only concerned about Chrome on Android - not iOS.

Any solution?

---

Update:
I also tried

```
    var lockOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;

    lockOrientation("portrait-primary");
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with CSS - although it's not ideal - I've yet to test this on many devices. Hope this is of some use to people who want to lock orientation on web.

```
@media (max-height: 480px) and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px) { 
html{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
       -moz-transform-origin: left top;
        -ms-transform-origin: left top;
         -o-transform-origin: left top;
            transform-origin: left top;
    width: 320px; /*this is the iPhone screen width.*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
        left: 0
}
}
```